# AWS CDK | Get ECS Fargate service/Task assigned public IP

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk

I'm trying to get the assigned public IP address of an ECS service but I couldn't find a way to reference it.

```js
const backendService = new ecs.FargateService(
      this,
      "EcsBackendAppService",
      {
        cluster: backendCluster,
        taskDefinition: backendTaskDefinition,
        desiredCount: 1,
        assignPublicIp: true,
        securityGroups: [vpcDefaultSecurityGroup],

        serviceName: "backend",
      }
    );
```

Is it possible to get the public IP in CDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible, because the public IP address will be different for each task that ECS launches - if the task is restarted for any reason, the IP will change.

Comment: actually, it is important, I need this IP address at the moment. if it changes that is not important because I catch the new IP again.

Comment: That's not how CDK works. CDK generates cloudformation templates, it cannot fetch any data "at the moment", you'll need to use the SDK for that.

Answer (score -1):

> Could it be possible to get the public IP in CDK?

Seems not, at least natively from the Construct's attributes.

Looking at [FargateService](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_ecs/FargateService.html), [TaskDefinition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_ecs/TaskDefinition.html) and [ContainerDefinition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_ecs/ContainerDefinition.html) Constructs' attributes, there's no reference to network interface or attachment, or even to private or public IP.

Looking at [ecs describe_tasks](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/2.0.33/reference/ecs/describe-tasks.html) SDK, the response includes the network interfaces of the containers within the tasks. Although the response template only show `privateIpv4Address`. So you need to confirm if this will also how the public IP. `networkInterfaces` information is not present in `describe_services` and `describe_container_instances` SDK calls.

With this information, you can try to use [AwsCustomResource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.custom_resources/AwsCustomResource.html) Construct and do [AwsSdkCall](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.custom_resources/AwsSdkCall.html) to try fetch the IP.

psuedocode:

```
taskDetails = cr.AwsCustomResource(self, "GetNetworkInterfaceCustomResource",
    on_update=cr.AwsSdkCall( # will also be called for a CREATE event
        service="ECS",
        action="describeTasks",
        parameters={
            "cluster": "myEcsCluster",
            "tasks": [myEcsTask]
        },
    physical_resource_id=cr.PhysicalResourceId.from_response("taskArn")),
    policy=cr.AwsCustomResourcePolicy.from_sdk_calls(
        resources=cr.AwsCustomResourcePolicy.ANY_RESOURCE
    )
)

networkInterfaces = taskDetails["tasks][0]["containers"][0]["networkInterfaces"]
```

Not that custom resource will create an additional Lambda function.

Comment: This code will not work as written, the custom resource doesn't simply return the SDK payload at synth time.